# Websphere Security Configuration for Apache CXF WebServices

Tags: web-services, soap, websphere, cxf

I am currently trying to configure security in Websphere 8/9 for the CXF soap Web-Services in our application.

Websphere Console is currently unable to see the CXF Web-Services, however we require Websphere to see them to configure security.

I have found some documentation which suggests that this is not possible:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html

Does anyone know of any way round this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the built in libraries rather than CXF, as WAS is able to monitor those libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, we already have an application working for many clients hosted in various different containers, and things are working well. We now have a client who wish to use websphere security (on top of our existing security). Ideally we don't want to make changes which could impact on existing clients.